# How to link found shape edges by lines?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a Python script that detects shape edges on a picture. I need to link that edges by lines.
Does anyone have any advice on how to do it, or a better way how to find shape edges and then link them?

Thanks in advance.

```
def dstf(path):
    img = image(path)
    (H, W) = img.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, scalefactor = 1.0, size = (W, H),
    mean=(104.00698793, 116.66876762, 122.67891434),
    swapRB = False, crop = False)
    net.setInput(blob)

    hed = net.forward()
    hed = cv2.resize(hed[0, 0], (W, H))
    hed = (255 * hed).astype("uint8")

    dst = cv2.cornerHarris(np.float32(hed), 2, 3, 0.04)
    dst = cv2.dilate(dst, None)

    img[dst > 0.01 * dst.max()] = [0, 0, 255]

    return img
```

Found edges:

[image: Found edges]

Original:

[image: Original]

Comment: I'd question the whole approach... and the presentation of the issue. you aren't employing a neural network to find corners on a *chess board*. what is this for?